# How to cache/speed Wordpress queries for logged in users?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, database-performance, bluehost

Wordpress generates an awful lot of sql queries.

We used 'WP Fastest Cache' which creates static html pages from your platform and caches them. Howevr for logged in users, the static pages wont work.

Here is what I am seeing. 122 queries, 7.8s spent in db time! Moreover as you can see all the queries are pretty fast (~0.05s). Hence caching the queries is not going to help

[image]

I am using bluehost to deploy and mysql db.

Whats the best way to optimize this. Is there a way to run all queries in parallel on mysql or some other elegant solution?

I am thinking of building this on heroku using rails, but we dont have enough time currently so we have to figure out a way to optimize the db.

Comment: Seeing that the queries you show all read the same table, with different "option_name" parameters, all LIMIT 1 makes me think: Why do you ask this table for one thing at a time? Why don't you just send ONE query to ask for everything. This will likely save you a bunch of useless queries and their associated overhead: Only one query needs to be parsed, table data to be read, data to be sent to PHP...

Comment: Its a small snapshot of all 122 queries.  We are using pluginhunt theme and the code is pretty convulated to start customizing. Looking for a silver bullet but seems like there isnt one. If we cache 122 quereis for all users with userid as the key, its a lot of stuff to cache. + we dont know if thats doable.

Comment: 122 queries to generate a page - that's crazy :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Moreover as you can see all the queries are pretty fast

Those queries aren't so fast. `0.1s` for a simple lookup on the options table is very slow.

All of the queries in the image you posted are on the options table. I'm not sure if most of your queries are option queries or not, but if you want to reduce the total number of option queries, you can use the `autoload` parameter on [`update_option`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) or [`add_option`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option). From the documentation:

> **$autoload** 
>   (string) (optional) Should this option be automatically loaded by the function [wp_load_alloptions()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_load_alloptions) (puts options into object cache on each page load)? Valid values: yes or no.

If you autoload your options they will all be fetched in a single query. This will reduce the total number of queries, but as a mentioned before, your queries shouldn't be taking that long to begin with.

For existing options, you will have to delete them first and then re-add them using the `autoload` parameter:

```
$val = get_option('some_option');
delete_option('some_option');
update_option('some_option', $val, true);
```

By default, when you create options they are set to autoload so it is a bit odd that you have so many options that aren't autoloading.

Comment: Accepting the answer because you provide atleast some wordpress specific optimizations. We however ended up implementing the app ourselves and hosting it on Heroku instead of using Wordpress because it was too hairy to change the code of different plugins and the theme.